# Improving specific SQL Server Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have the following query which is being executed in SQL Server 2008 R2 several times a day on multiple client databases.

```
UPDATE    Propane.RecordKey
With (TabLock)
SET              LookupKey = System.Param_RecordKey.LookupKey
FROM         Propane.RecordKey INNER JOIN 
                  System.Param_RecordKey ON 
                  Propane.RecordKey.IndexId = System.Param_RecordKey.IndexId
                  And Propane.RecordKey.RecordNumber = System.Param_RecordKey.RecordNumber                       
                  AND Propane.RecordKey.LookupKey <> System.Param_RecordKey.LookupKey
WHERE     (System.Param_RecordKey.ParameterKeyId = @key)
```

I am looking for any suggestion on how to make this query run as quickly as possible.   Currently I am having delays which can last from a few seconds to a minute or more.

The  performance is not consistent, with some cases where many records are affected are running relatively quickly and other cases with many fewer affected records running quite slowly. On my test machine the performance is generally acceptable (i.e a few seconds for 10,000+ records), but there is significant delays occurring on some of our clients.

This extreme variation which I am unable to account for, combined with my admittedly limited knowledge of how to tweak query performance, makes me reluctant to experiment with alterations which may not show much benefit and might make the query run worse.

The table being updated, RecordKey, is read from frequently (hundreds to thousands of times a day) and updated occasionally (a few times per day).

RecordKey's primary index is IndexId and RecordNumber.  Param_RecordKey has key fields of ParameterKeyId, IndexId, and RecordNumber.  I.e. I am filtering and joining on the primary key fields of both tables. All these fields are ints.

RecordKey will have hundreds of thousands to a few million records in it.  Param_RecordKey will have just the records being updated. Typically Param_RecordKey will contain a few thousand records, though 10's of thousands of records are common and 100,000 or more is possible.

The LookupKey field in both tables is varchar(27). In most cases the text stored in the field will have a length between 5-10 characters.  Lengths of 10-15 characters are common and lengths over 20 are rare. In the vast majority of cases the values in the respective LookUpKeys will be the same, i.e. few records will be updated. In rare cases ALL of the records will be updated.

One question I have is: Would I get better performance if I were to remove the check Propane.RecordKey.LookupKey <> System.Param_RecordKey.LookupKey? i.e. if I were to update all records and not just those with different LookupKeys. My expectation is that the time to update all the records would be greater than just updating those that have changed, but I'm uncertain this is true.

Any advice on how to improve this query would be greatly appreciated.

---

**April 9th 2013,  New info.**

After removing the With (TabLock) and testing the changes at the client's site, the results are mixed.  In some cases the query executed much faster, in some cases much slower, and in many cases there was no significant change in how long it took to process the records.

Since making the change did not result a significant and repeatable improvement in performance, I'm leaving this question open and marked as unanswered. I am still interested in any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Is there contention on the updates? Does this statement need to be atomic?

Comment: Where is the execution plan?

Comment: Do you really need the WITH (TABLOCK)?

Comment: You have several JOIN's - are there indices on all the foreign key columns involved?

Comment: The larger process should prevent contentions.  I think I originally added TABLOCK because in testing (i.e. on my own machine without other users) it yielded better performance.  However as IWade Rock below points out it might be the source of the performance problem on the multi-user client environment. I have removed the TABLOCK and will see how that affect performance in the wild.

Comment: There are two indices on RecordKey: Primary index is IndexId and RecordNumber in that order (both ints).  Secondary, non-unique index is on IndexId, LookupKey, and RecordNumber in that order.  The Secondary index is how records are typically read and is the clustering index to improved read performance.  Reads are MUCH more common and overall more important for speed.  Table Param_RecordKey has a primary key on ParameterKeyId, IndexId, and RecordNumber.  Param_RecordKey does not have any secondary indices.

Answer (score 2):

The table hint TABLOCK is likely to take an exclusive lock on the table being updated. Such locks are not compatible with other locks, even shared locks, and will impact performance. If a query requires an exclusive table lock it will have to wait until no other locks are taken. Remove the hint and let the database engine decide the locking strategy - it's quite good at it. Performance on your development machine will be acceptable because you are (probably) the only person accessing the table and as such no other locks are taken

Answer (score 0):

One of the best improvement I've seen in such script with a variable was to create a dynamic query and converting the variable into a sql, and then executing the resulting sql.  Of course, be sure indexes are rebuild (or at least statistics up to date) while doing this.  DBCC TRACEON 2301 and 8780 could also help.

Answer (score 0):

I got two solutions for you, the second one should probably work faster than what you have now.

```
UPDATE    Propane.RecordKey
With (TabLock)
SET              LookupKey = System.Param_RecordKey.LookupKey
FROM         Propane.RecordKey K ,  System.Param_RecordKey R
 ON 
              K.IndexId = R.IndexId
              And K.RecordNumber = R.RecordNumber                       
              AND K.LookupKey <> R.LookupKey
WHERE     (R.ParameterKeyId = @key)


UPDATE    Propane.RecordKey
With (TabLock)
SET              LookupKey = System.Param_RecordKey.LookupKey
FROM         Propane.RecordKey K ,  System.Param_RecordKey R
 ON 
              K.IndexId = R.IndexId
              And K.RecordNumber = R.RecordNumber                       
               WHERE     (R.ParameterKeyId = @key) and K.LookupKey not in          (Select LookupKey from System.Param_RecordKey)
```